# Laravel relation - sum with group by

Tags: laravel, relation

Tyring to list sum of group with hasmany relation. but doesnt work. Returns empty result.

my model:

```
public function inventory()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Inventory')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}
```

and my controller is below.

```
$products = Product::where('firm_id', $firm_id)
    ->with(['category', 'cost', 'inventory' => function ($query) use ($firm_id) {
        $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(inventories.quantity) as paidsum"))->groupBy('addresses.id')
        ->join('addresses', function($q){
            $q->on('addresses.id', '=', 'inventories.address_id');
        });
    }])
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
```

Comment: why not just try [`withSum(['inventory'])`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions)

Comment: it returns only sum, i need to group it with addresses. turkey: 20, usa: 50 etc.